# time.h clock() broken on OS X?

Tags: c, macos, clock, darwin, time.h

Am I going mad? I'm running this on x86_64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Clock: %f\n", clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Clock: %f\n", clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Clock: %f\n", clock() / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

> Clock: 0.002880
>   Clock: 0.002968
>   Clock: 0.003019

It clearly waits for a second at the `sleep(1)` lines, but the output is clearly wrong.

If that doesn't work, is there a portable C alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm an idiot. `clock()` returns **processor time** used.

Comment: yup and since it's sleeping it's probably not using any :)

Comment: For the record, I was following documentation here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/, I've written to them to inform them of their error!

Comment: @joerick Just use cppreference.com. They contain very few such errors and if you find one, you can fix it right there.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an variable  
`time_t t1,t2;`  
`t1 = time(NULL);`  
`sleep(1);`  
`t2 = time(NULL);`  

You can debug and view the values of t1 and t2.  
I think you can take an reference from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/